# android adding views dynamically

Tags: android, view, dynamic-data

I am adding views dynamically in a linear layout as follows:

xml:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/part1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
 </LinearLayout>
```

java:

```
    View linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.part1);

    ((LinearLayout) linearLayout).removeAllViews();

    for (int i = 0; i  < 15; i ++){


        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(String.valueOf(i));
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lay = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        tv.setLayoutParams(lay);
        tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.msg);
        tv.setId(i);
        ((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(tv);

    }
```

Now i have two questions:

1) the text views are added horizontally correctly but if not fitting screensize, some of them won't appear, how to force it to continue adding in a new line once the horizontal space is full ?

2) textviews are added from left to right, how to add them from right to left ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how ViewGroups work, in this case, LinearLayout will add items horizontally or vertically without making position calculations for you unless you explicitly specify (jumping to next line is not one of them...), think of it as an item holder that will show items only on the space you specify for it (thats why some of the elements disappear...),  by default the way LinearLayout arrange items is from left to right or up to down, if this do not fit your needs, you could go for any of the ViewGroup options android has, the most important might be:

RelativeLayout
FrameLayout
TableLayout
AbsoluteLayout(not recommended)

If you need some sort of Free Draw on the screen, you can always go for a View object, override onDraw, and play with the canvas of that object...

Regards!

Comment: Thanks Martin for passing by the question, so appreciated .. Actually i know the other types of layouts but they won't be suitable for my design .. i have just found sth similar to what i am thinking in but i will still try it, then check right to left issue, it is called flow layout ..
https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout